# Connect to an IRC bouncer with Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, irc, chat, irc-bouncer

I would like to set up a bouncer on my rootserver and connect there from my PC, so I will see all messages during the last 30 minutes that I missed when I reconnect to a channel.

Is this possible in Thunderbird Chat? And how?

Comment: This is a very vague question, there are a great number of IRC bouncers/proxies/relays you could use, and then connect to an IRC client. My first suggestion is to find a real IRC client you like (and not an IM client that can 'kind of' do IRC). Then find a bouncer you like, and clarify you question, assuming the FAQs for the chosen software don't answer this for you. I personally use tmux+weechat on a server, which I can use for relay if I ever feel like not just connecting via ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [`bip`](https://bip.milkypond.org/), an IRC proxy, that keeps connected to your preferred IRC servers.

It is easy to install and configure on arch or debian [with this HowTo](https://flexion.org/posts/2014-04-bip-irc-proxy.html). That HowTo works already quite well. I only had a bit of hazzle to find out, how to **connect via ssl to irc.hackint.org**, solution:

```
network {
    name = "hackint";
    server { host = "irc.eu.hackint.org"; port = 6697; };
    ssl = true; 
};
```

There seems to be a problem with Thunderbird still, so I use it with Pidgin now instead to connect to bip on my server an always stay logged in at my preferred channels and get messages that were sent when I was offline, I otherwise would have missed.

---

Since the Howto is down, here are the main steps:

## Installing BIP

Installing BIP is simple for both Arch Linux and Debian.

#### Debian

I run BIP on Debian Wheezy with the backport repository enabled.

```
sudo apt-get -t wheezy-backports install bip
sudo sed -i 's/ENABLED=0/ENABLED=1/' /etc/default/bip
```

#### Arch Linux

```
pacman -S bip
systemctl enable bip
```

## Create a user

The next thing to do is create a username and password and BIP provides it's own utility for doing this called bipmkpw. Replace 'username' with whatever you want your BIP 'username' to be. This name has no relation to any IRC usernames so it can be anything.

```
bipmkpw username
```

Enter a password when prompted. The password will then be output as a hash. Make a note of both the hashed and un-hashed values somewhere, you will need them later.
Create a certificate

We don't want the username and password being sent as clear-text, so we will create an SSL certificate for BIP to use.

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -x509 -keyout bip.pem -out bip.pem
```

Move the certificate to /var/lib/bip

```
sudo mv bip.pem /var/lib/bip
```

Change ownership and permissions of the certificate to the user bip which was created automatically when the package was installed.

```
sudo chown bip:bip /var/lib/bip/bip.pem
sudo chmod 600 /var/lib/bip/bip.pem
```

## Configure BIP

Here is example configuration for BIP. Copy it to /etc/bip.conf, modify it accordingly and then change the ownership and permissions.

```
sudo chown bip:bip /etc/bip.conf
sudo chmod 640 /etc/bip.conf
```

- [Example configuration](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/a4ef86ad38a9aa7fd030)

If you require any clarification about what the configuration options do then man bip.conf is your friend.
Start BIP

Now that BIP is configured, it can be started.

#### Debian

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bip start
```

#### Arch Linux

```
sudo systemctl start bip
```

Client configuration

I use HexChat, but other IRC clients are available. I add a new Network to HexChat for each of the IRC networks I defined in /etc/bip.conf. The screen shot below shows how I configure a BIP network in HexChat.

## HexChat BIP Configuration

[image]

## Password format

The Password is the most important and confusing item. This is for BIP, not for any IRC network. Remember the unhashed password? That goes here but with a twist. The format for the password is:

```
bipusername:unhashedbippassword:bipnetwork
```

Bipnetwork? What is that? It is from the following section of `/etc/bip.conf` on the server?

```
network {
    name = "freenode";
    server { host = "chat.freenode.net"; port = 6667; };
};
```

A more practical example:

```
myuser:S3cr3tP@$$w0rd:freenode
```

## Conclusion

And that's it! We are now perpetually connected to IRC, can connect to BIP proxy from multiple devices in a completely transparent and seamless manner. Moreover, the logs for all channels are saved and automatically rotated on the server.

If you looking for an alternative to BIP, then try ZNC.

## References

- https://wiki.linaro.org/Resources/HowTo/BIP
- http://nerderati.com/2010/11/perpetual-irc-the-proxy-edition/
- http://stevengorrell.com/bip-irc-proxy/

Comment: the site is down, bit still in the archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20140718094511/http://flexion.org/posts/2014-04-bip-irc-proxy.html